# How do I change the name of Keys in a dictionary using a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dictionary

I am looking to replace all the keys in this dictionary -

```
L = [{"V":"S001"}, {"V": "S002"}, {"VI": "S001"}, {"VI": "S005"}, {"VII":"S005"}, {"V":"S009"},{"VIII":"S007"}]
```

Here is the dataframe that has unique keys and name

```
     dx new_col
0  VIII    dx_1
1    VI    dx_2
2     V    dx_3
3   VII    dx_4
```

The output I am looking is -

```
L = [{"dx_3":"S001"}, {"dx_3": "S002"}, {"dx_2": "S001"}, {"dx_2": "S005"}, {"dx_4":"S005"}, {"dx_3":"S009"},{"dx_1":"S007"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a mapping series from the given dataframe, then replace the keys using the mapping series inside a list comprehension

```
s = df.set_index('dx')['new_col']
[{s.get(k, k): v for k, v in d.items()} for d in L]
```

---

```
[{'dx_3': 'S001'},
 {'dx_3': 'S002'},
 {'dx_2': 'S001'},
 {'dx_2': 'S005'},
 {'dx_4': 'S005'},
 {'dx_3': 'S009'},
 {'dx_1': 'S007'}]
```